# Restriction of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and $A \in L(V)$. Suppose nullity$(A) =$ nullity$(A^2)$. Prove that $\bar A \in L(V/$Nullity$(A))$, defined by $A[v] = [Av]$ is well defined and $\bar A$ is an isomorphism.

I have the note but I don't understand. Someone explains me, please
The note: 
$$
\vec u'\in [\vec u] \implies \vec u'-\vec u \in N(A)
$$
Therefore $Au'=Au \implies [Au'] = [Au]$. So $\bar A$ is well defined.

Answer (score 1):

To explain the note: we want to show that $\bar A$ is well-defined. That is, we need to show 
that the definition of $\bar A$ does not depend on the choice of representative for a given equivalence class. More explicitly, we need to show the following:

> For any $u,u' \in V$: if $u' \in [u]$, then $Au' \in [Au] = \bar A[u]$.

Now, using the definition of $[u] \in V/$Null$(A)$, this means that we need to show:

> For any $u,u' \in V$: if $u - u' \in $Null$(A)$, then $Au - Au' \in $Null$(A)$.

This is precisely what the note shows.

In order to show that $\bar A$ is an isomorphism, it suffices to show that Null$(\bar A) = [0]$.

Comment: I am sorry. I don't see the link between A bar and A in the proof. A bar is A apply on V(without nullity of A), right? And the proof focus on A only; then conclusion is on A bar!!!

Comment: @user73195 see my edit.  Remember that $\bar A([u]) := [Au]$, for some $u \in [u]$.  The proof shows that $\bar A[u]$ is the same regardless of which $u \in [u]$ is chosen.

Comment: to prove A(bar) isomorphism, I have to show that nullity (A) ={0}, right? I would like to confirm again: A(bar) is A applied on some special subspace of V, right?

Comment: $A /$Null$(A)$ is not a *subspace* of $V$; it is the quotient space.  What you're trying to show is that Null$(A) = \{[0]\}$.  That is, if $\bar A[u] = [0]$, then $[0] = [u]$, which to say that $u \in [0]$.

Comment: Remember that the elements of Null$(A)$ are of the form $[u] = \{u' \in V: A(u - u') = 0\}$ for arbitrary $u \in V$.  Note that $[u]$ is not an **element** of the vector space $V$.

Comment: No, that would be $V \setminus B$, which is not generally a vector space.

Comment: for some reasons, I cannot access to chat room. I saw your message there but don't see the box for me to reply. I am sorry

Comment: Strange.  If that's the case, it's fine to comment here. At any rate, can you clarify what confuses you?  I would check your textbook for the definition of $A/B$.